# Query list of email aliases in Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

What ways can i query my Exchange 2007 server for all email aliases used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry i didn't answer sooner, I ended up working a bit on my Google-fu and came up with the following which gave me the entire list of email addresses, primary or aliases for my entire domain.  Thanks!

http://exchangepedia.com/2005/09/how-to-export-all-email-addresses-from-a-domain.html

Answer (score 3):

This should get you a list

```
Get-Mailbox | fl UserPrincipalName, Emailaddresses, PrimarySMTPaddress
```

This command will show you the user, smtp addresses and the primary address.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is mate:

```
Get-Mailbox -resultSize unlimited | foreach{
 $emails= $_ | select -expand EmailAddresses | where {$_.PrefixString -eq 'smtp'} | sort IsPrimaryAddress -desc | foreach {$_.smtpAddress}
 [string]::join(",",$emails)
} > C:\alias.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This will output a list in human-readable format. I couldn't quickly figure out how to remove the "SmtpAddress" line on the first item, but you can edit that out fairly easily in Notepad.

```
Write-Host "SMTP Aliases";
foreach ($mailbox in Get-Mailbox | Sort-Object OrganizationalUnit, DisplayName) {
    Write-Host;
    Write-Host $mailbox.DisplayName;
    Write-Host $mailbox.OrganizationalUnit;
    Write-Host "========================";
    Get-Mailbox $mailbox -filter {EmailAddresses -notlike '*X400:*' -and EmailAddresses -notlike '*X500:*'} | Select-Object -expand EmailAddresses | Select-Object SmtpAddress
    Write-Host;
    Write-Host "---------------------------------------------";
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
Administrator
domain.local/Users
========================

SmtpAddress
-----------
Administrator@webdomain.com
Administrator@domain.local

---------------------------------------------

Discovery Search Mailbox
domain.local/Users
========================
DiscoverySearchMailbox{D919BA05-46A6-415f-80AD-000000000000}@webdomain.com
DiscoverySearchMailbox{D919BA05-46A6-415f-80AD-000000000000}@domain.local

---------------------------------------------

Jane Doe
domain.local/Users
========================
info@webdomain.com
helpdesk@webdomain.com
jane@webdomain.com
jane@domain.local

---------------------------------------------
```